# what is super.format in quill?

Tags: javascript, format, super, quill

I am quite bogged down with the syntax here: role of the super and recursive manner.

In the code below, super.format is written inside the function called "format". As I search for the definition of super, it's parent class, which I guess LinkBot here. And this LinkBot class has a function calle d format. So, it looks to me this is made in the way of recursive.

And also super.formats() is defined inside formats(), which really seems awkward to me..

Can anyone help me what this is..?

Looking forward to finding anyone who saves from this jungle..

```
import Parchment from 'parchment';

class LinkBlot extends Parchment.Inline {
  static create(url) {
    let node = super.create();
    return node;
  }

  static formats(domNode) {
    return domNode.getAttribute('href') || true;
  }

  format(name, value) {
    if (name === 'link' && value) {
      this.domNode.setAttribute('href', value);
    } else {
      super.format(name, value);
    }
  }

  formats() {
    let formats = super.formats();
    formats['link'] = LinkBlot.formats(this.domNode);
    return formats;
  }
}

Parchment.register(LinkBlot);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more related on how class work. I just take your class as example to avoid overwhelming you.

```
//     Child class    Parent Class
class LinkBlot extends Parchment.Inline {
}
```

and yes, super refer to parent class verbally which means **Parchment.Inline**.

Parent class - `Parchment.Inline` has `create()`, `format()`, `formats()` methods

```
class Parchment.Inline {
   create() { ... }
   format(name, value) { ... }
   formats() { ... }
   ...
}
```

---

Child class `LinkBlot` inherits Parchment.Inline (Parent class) functionalities by using `extends`

Take a example, you may inherits some skills/behaviours from your mother/father, like:

- *tidy up the house every week.*

At the same time, you may evolve and override their skills/behaviours to have your own version

- If I have energy, use my own version

  - *tidy up the house every day*
- but if I tired, do in parent way

  - *tidy up the house every week.*

**LinkBlot** is doing the same, it is overriding the parent `format()` to have its own version of `format()`.

- if (name === 'link' && value), do it in my own way

  - *this.domNode.setAttribute('href', value);*
- if not, use parent version

  - *super.format(name, value);*

```
class LinkBlot extends Parchment.Inline {
  ...

  // overriding parent format() and create my own version
  format(name, value) {
    // if the following conditions meet, use my logic to set domNode attribut.
    if (name === 'link' && value) {
      this.domNode.setAttribute('href', value);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, use the parent version
      super.format(name, value);
    }
  }
}
```

The same principle applies to `formats()` and `create()` as well.